# Replace a special char with a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am building a category filter but, the categories will be determined by my end user.  So, I have to get a set of categories from the user, separated by "|" symbol and then put them up as checkbox separated categories.  Like this:

List: Student | Employee | Faculty

Catfitler : I wanted a checkbox for each category - Student, Faculty and Employee

I have a jquery event to remove special character "|" and I got the string as Student Employee Faculty

HTML:

```
<span class="work">Student | Employee | Faculty </span>
<br>
<button class="b">remove special characters</button>
<p>We can make this remove only what we want.</p>
```

JS:

```
function removeSpl() {
  var ns = $('.work').text();
  // Just remove commas and periods - regex can do any chars
  ns = ns.replace(/([|])+/g, '');
  $('.work').text(ns)
}
$( ".b" ).click(function() {
 removeSpl();
});
```

I want a checkbox to be added in front of every category.  How to achieve this?

Comment: This is perhaps more difficult as the "Student" has no leading | - and what if the users enter "Good Students | Bad Students | Other Students" it gets even more fun

Comment: I can't help but wonder why you do not provide checkboxes as options to the user in the first place. Would be more intuitive than pipe separated strings.

Comment: so create a checkbox element and instead of text you append html.

Comment: Is there a way to add "|" char in the front and replace it with a checkbox? @ Mark Schultheiss

Comment: @ Anurag Srivastava  and  @epascarello  I'm giving the user a choice to set it as radio buttons or check box.  So, I just get the raw data separated by "|" and then insert a checkbox or radio button accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several assumptions built into this, prefix all the string being the more interesting.
I put in a temporary element then replace it with a real checkbox.

Probably should wrap each of the text in a `<label></label>` but that was not part of the question.

Does NOT account for "||" entry.
Pretty verbose but that is conducive to what is happening.

```js
function removeSpl() {
  let wrk = $('.work');
  var ns = wrk.text();
  let tempcb = '<cb />';
  // Just remove commas and periods - regex can do any chars
  ns = ns.replace(/([|])+/g, tempcb);
  ns = tempcb + ns;
  wrk.html(ns);
  wrk.find('cb')
    .replaceWith("<input type='checkbox' />");
}
$(".b").one('click', function() {
  removeSpl();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="work">Student | Employee | Faculty </span>
<br>
<button class="b">remove special characters</button>
<p>We can make this remove only what we want.</p>
```

Comment: One small problem with your answer.  If I click the button twice, then the answer changes to <checkbox> Student Employee Faculty - Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Just allow them to do it once

Comment: I edited it to just allow it once -in the limits of this question, that works, there might be other ways like disable the button etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) your list by `|` delimiter and then iterate over this newly created array and append checkboxes and do some other stuff. Here an example:

```js
const list = 'Student|Employee|Faculty';
const wrapper = $('#wrapper');

list.split('|').forEach(str => {
 let cb = $('<input>', {
  type: 'checkbox',
  name: str
 });
 
 wrapper.append(cb);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='wrapper'>

</div>
```

From my point of view you don't need any regex patterns to achieve your requirement. You can split your list by any delimiter you want.

Comment: What about trailing/leading spaces? What about spaces between words (single or multiple)?

Comment: Simply use trim() method to trim them.

Comment: @dganenco - Your code gives me checkboxes but I want my output like this: <checkbox>Student <checkbox>Employee <checkbox>Faculty.  Your code gives me <checkbox><checkbox><checkbox>.  Can you help me to separate the categories and add a checkbox?